# Corona SDK Display Group Issue - Where is the error in this code?

Tags: coronasdk

Is anyone able to see the logic flaw in this lua code for Corona?

The concept is you create a new "extended" Display Object (e.g. MyGroup:new(...)), after which you can then insert objects into this using percentages for it's position in the parent (so no need to use pixcels counts).

Issue - The issue is the objects draw are roughly in the correct spots but just a little bit out?   I have a feeling it is something due to perhaps coordinates changing in the parent in the "self:insert(displayO)" line?

main.lua

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- HELPERS 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function rpadString (str, len, char)
    if char == nil then char = ' ' end
    return  (str .. string.rep(char, len - #str))
end

function drawBorder(obj)
    local b = obj.contentBounds 

    local myRectangle = display.newRect(b.xMin, b.yMin, obj.contentWidth, obj.contentHeight)
    -- print ("Rect X,Y,Width,Height: ", b.xMin, b.yMin, obj.contentWidth, obj.contentHeight)
    myRectangle.strokeWidth = 1
    myRectangle:setFillColor(140, 140, 140, 1)
    if obj.gcGroupName then
        -- Group
        myRectangle:setStrokeColor(100, 250, 180)
        myRectangle.strokeWidth = 1
    else
        -- Image/Rect
        myRectangle:setStrokeColor(250, 180, 180)
        myRectangle.strokeWidth = 2
    end


end

function dumpDisplayObjects(doParent, level)
    drawBorder(doParent)
    if doParent.numChildren then
        for i=doParent.numChildren,1,-1 do
            local doChild = doParent[i]
            dumpDisplayObjects(doChild, level + 1)
        end
    end
end

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- MAIN 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
require "MyGroup"

print "RUNNING ........................................."
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )

-- Create Toolbar Area at Bottom
local mainGroup = MyGroup:new("Main Group", 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
local toolbarArea = MyGroup:new("Inventory", 0,0,0,0)
mainGroup:GcInsertLRTB(toolbarArea, 0, 100, 80, 100, "Inventory")    -- Percentages Used

-- Draw Rectangle 1
local toolbarAreaImage = display.newImage( "toolbarArea_button.png", 0, 0)
toolbarArea:GcInsertLRTB(toolbarAreaImage, 0, 20, 0, 100, "Inventory Button")

-- -- Setup Toolbar Group
-- local toolbarAreaToolbar = MyGroup:new("InventoryToolbar", 0, 0, 1, 1)
-- toolbarArea:GcInsertLRTB(toolbarAreaToolbar, 20, 100, 0, 100, "Toolbar")
--  -- 
-- -- Draw Rectangle 2
-- local rect2 = display.newRoundedRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000, 5)
-- rect2.strokeWidth = 1
-- rect2:setStrokeColor(140, 140, 140)
-- rect2:setFillColor(140, 140, 140, 100)
-- toolbarAreaToolbar:GcInsertLRTB(rect2, 0, 100, 0, 100, "Rect2")

-- Debug Display
dumpDisplayObjects(toolbarArea, 1)
```

MyGroup.lua

```
MyGroup = {}

function MyGroup:new(name, left, top, targetWidth, targetHeight)
    -- Inherit from Group
    myGroup = display.newGroup()

    -- Work Around (Dummy Display Object Insertion) (See Note 1)
    myGroup.dummyDO = display.newCircle( myGroup, 10, 10, 1 )
    myGroup.dummyDO:setFillColor(1,1,1,1)
    myGroup.dummyDO.debugComment = "Dummy Display Object"
    myGroup:insert(myGroup.dummyDO)

    myGroup.myGroupName = name      
    myGroup.debugComment = name
    myGroup.targetWidth = targetWidth
    myGroup.targetHeight = targetHeight
    myGroup.x = left
    myGroup.y = top


    function myGroup:GcInsertLRTB(displayO, leftP, rightP, topP, bottomP, debugComment)
        self:insert(displayO)   -- <=== DOES THIS UPSET THINGS FOR THE PARENT???

        -- Remove Work Around Dummy Display Object (See Note 1)
        if self.dummyDO then 
            self.dummyDO:removeSelf() 
            self.dummyDO = nil
        end

        displayO:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)
        displayO.x = leftP * 0.01 * self.targetWidth
        displayO.y =  (topP * 0.01) * self.targetHeight

        -- Scale Display Object (or set target's if adding another MyGroup)
        if not displayO.myGroupName then
            -- Not a MyGroup
            local xScale = (self.targetWidth * (rightP - leftP)/100) / displayO.width  
            local yScale = (self.targetHeight * (bottomP - topP)/100) / displayO.height
            displayO:scale(xScale, yScale)
        else
            -- Inserted object is a MyGroup
            displayO.targetWidth = self.targetWidth * (rightP - leftP)/100
            displayO.targetHeight = self.targetHeight * (bottomP - topP)/100 
            displayO:scale(1,1)  -- TODO: Probably don't need this
        end

    end

    return myGroup
end

-- Class Variables

-- Class Methods

return MyGroup
```

Comment: I've just created a new project using this code, replacing the toolbarArea_button.png asset. I really can't figure out what the problem is, can you create a clearer, more precise example? (start by removing the commented code, not sure if that's what's causing the problem or what?).

Comment: I'm starting to think the concept might be flawed?  That is, if one of the groups changes, there won't be a trigger event to reset my objects based on percentages.  What do you think?  Perhaps need to stick with the Corona setting via pixcel distances?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is probably a bug:  "myGroup:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint) causes items to move"

That is:

- AnscaMobile blog states: “The main difference is that the default reference point for a group is display.TopLeftReferencePoint,…
- Applying the already existing default to a group changes the locations of items in the group where it should not: e.g. the code:  "myGroup:setReferencePoint(display.TopLeftReferencePoint)

So the workaround might have to be in the class to do an if/then check to make sure the setReferencePoint is only applied to non-groups.

Raised with anscamobile as case #14049